# send observable while object is not instanciate

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a logic problem that I can't solve with observable when it's feel do-able. It is part of (I expect) a factory pattern ?

The problem is :
-I have a Class 'Cl'   with a parameter 'p'.
-In 'Cl' constructor, I make an http request to get the correct value for p (Yeah, this part feel very strange too)
-'Cl' has a getter which return 'p' or part of it.

When I do `instance = new CL(); instance.get();` Of course my http request hasn't finish yet. so 'p' is undefined.
Can the getter return an observable that get accept only when p is getting define ?

maybe some code explain better the situation :

```
import {lot of thigs } from '@angular/core'; //and RxJs

@Component({
//...
})
export class aClass {
private p:any

constructor() {
    this.p = return this.Http.get('a/route')//let's say this request take AGE
    .map((response) => { 
        return response.json(); 
    });
}

//Obviously no working cause cause p isn't "define yet"
public getP(index){
    return this.p[index];
}

//I'd hope something like this would work but it doesn't.
public getObservableP(index): Observable<any>{
    return Observable.of(this.p[index]);
}

}
```

Can you tell me how to return an Observable (or a Promise if it should be) which will fulfill when p is instanciate please. Thanks.

(I have read several things about the http request in constuctor is bad, maybe my conception is wrong here).

Comment: First of all a promise is async so in your template us ?. to check if promise is completed.
Second try to save the promise. this.p = response;
And third maybe make a getter for this.p.

Comment: @Swoox sorry, I read twice, but I don't understand this.

Comment: you try to return an object that not exist. Cause your application is quicker then your promise.

Comment: indeed. That's why I'm looking for an Obersvable/promise that would resolve only when p is gettings instanciate. I could send this Observable/promise in the getter

Comment: Are you using this in the template?

Comment: Think the only way to achieve it like that is with a timeout. But that is ugly..

Comment: @Matsura 
Kind of. Let's say the code above is an angular service. My component call the getter and display the object it get send.

Comment: @Swoox No way I do that :s

Comment: Then try in the template instance?.valueToShow the ? will wait for your promise to resolve. https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: @Swoox I would agree, but that doesn't answer the question about how to do the getter properly. Which is the things I try to understand atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code posted acts as a service, the best thing would be to utilize the async pipe like this:

```
import {lot of thigs } from '@angular/core'; //and RxJs

@Component({
//...
})
export class aClass {
private p:any

constructor() {
    this.p = return this.Http.get('a/route')//let's say this request take AGE
    .map((response) => { 
        return response.json(); 
    });
}

public getP(index){
    return this.p;
}
}
```

In your component you would inject the aClass and in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let something of aClass.getP() | async">
    {{something}}
</div>
```

or

```
<p>{{aClass.getP() | async}}</p>
```

Comment: I guess that would work. 
Just to be sure, do you know a way for the getter to be asynchronous, instead of putting it in the template

Comment: You need to return an observable(like I wrote). Then you can use it in the component code to subscribe to it. Let's say you have a component that injects your `aClass` service and the service has a method getP that returns your observable. Then in your component you can write `this.aClass.getP().subscribe((result) => result);` In the subscribe block you can save the result into a variable, filter it, etc.